How can I run the same command in C# interactive in VS?
How can I run the same command in C# interactive in VS?
Usually CLI tools allow just to press the up arrow to get the previously typed command.
Is there a way to do something similar in C# interactive in Visual Studio? Pressing the up arrow just brings me one line up.
Is copy paster the only way to get the last typed command?
E.g. I typed Console.WriteLine(a);, then I pressed Enter. Now I want to execute the same Console.WriteLine(a); again. So, I am pressing the up arrow, but instead of getting the Console.WriteLine(a); typed in automatically, I am just going one line up.

> var a = "foo";
> Console.WriteLine(a);
foo
> 


@HansPassant, where can I see the help?

Quote: Type #help

This question is similar to: C# interactive window command history in VS 2015 Update 2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Filburt, the linked question looks similar indeed and if I came across that question I would probably be able to guess an answer to my question. But, I would unlikely to think searching for history keyword when faced with a necessity to run previous command. E.g. I was not able to come across the question you shared when I did my bit of research before posting this question. So, I would rather keep my question online for others.

@manymanymore closing as duplicate doesn't automatically qualify your question to be deleted. It will just stay but refer to existing answers to avoid posting nearly identical answers over and over again.

You probably want alt+up.
Typing #help in the interactive window shows useful keyboard shortcuts:
> #help
Keyboard shortcuts:
  Enter                If the current submission appears to be complete, evaluate it.  Otherwise, insert a new line.
  Ctrl-Enter           Within the current submission, evaluate the current submission.
                       Within a previous submission, append the previous submission to the current submission.
  Shift-Enter          Insert a new line.
  Escape               Clear the current submission.
  Alt-UpArrow          Replace the current submission with a previous submission.
  Alt-DownArrow        Replace the current submission with a subsequent submission (after having previously navigated backwards).
  Ctrl-Alt-UpArrow     Replace the current submission with a previous submission beginning with the same text.
  Ctrl-Alt-DownArrow   Replace the current submission with a subsequent submission beginning with the same text (after having previously navigated backwards).
  Ctrl-K, Ctrl-Enter   Paste the selection at the end of interactive buffer, leave caret at the end of input.
  Ctrl-E, Ctrl-Enter   Paste and execute the selection before any pending input in the interactive buffer.
  Ctrl-A               First press, select the submission containing the cursor.  Second press, select all text in the window.
REPL commands:
  #cls, #clear         Clears the contents of the editor window, leaving history and execution context intact.
  #help                Display help on specified command, or all available commands and key bindings if none specified.
  #reset               Reset the execution environment to the initial state and keep history, with the option to switch the runtime of the host process.
Script directives:
  #r                   Add a metadata reference to specified assembly and all its dependencies, e.g. #r "myLib.dll".
  #load                Load specified script file and execute it, e.g. #load "myScript.csx".
> 

You can change this by changing the keyboard shortcut for InteractiveConsole.HistoryPrevious.

